# How can I solve this error in selenium for a loop? InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath

Tags: html, selenium, loops, xpath

I have tried to make a for loop in selenium for a website to check if one of a few buttons is clickable and then click it and if not refresh it until it is clickable. Now with my Xpaths I get the error below the following code (InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression Xpath=...

It would be nice if you could help I haven't found anything that helps me yet!
Otherwise a different solution for my problem would be nice, too!
Thank you!

```
paths = ['Xpath=//*[@id="mms-app-root"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/button', 'Xpath=//*[@id="mms-app-root"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/button', 'Xpath=//*[@id="mms-app-root"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/button']

for i in range(len(paths)):
    if(len(wd.find_elements_by_xpath(paths[i])) > 0):
        wd.find_element_by_xpath(paths[i]).click()
        break
    else:                                                                                                          
        print('not available')
        time.sleep(8)
        wd.refresh()
        time.sleep(2)

InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression Xpath=//*[@id="mms-app-root"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/button because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to remove `Xpath=` prefix from expression to make it valid.